# Call logoff in Ant script

Tags: windows, ant, batch-file

I am trying to call the logoff command from my build.xml. I tried several combinations in my ant target such as :

```
<target name="bat">
<echo>Executing batch script</echo>
  <exec dir="C:\WINDOWS\system32" executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="logoff"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

But everytime, I get this error : 
"logoff is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

I don't know how to fix this issue.
Thanks for helping.

**EDIT:**

logoff.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="logoff" default="off" basedir=".">
    <target name="off">
        <exec executable="cmd">
            <arg value="/c"/> 
            <arg value="logoff"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

logoff_xml.bat:

```
@echo off
set ANT_HOME=W:\lib\org.apache.ant
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24 
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin 
set BUILD_PATH=W:\logoff.xml 
set ANT=call ant -buildfile %BUILD_PATH% 
%ANT% 
pause
```

echo %PATH% (with buid.xml bat target)

```
[exec] C:\Outils\GPS_510\bin;C:\Outils\GNATPRO_6.1.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system3
2;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Outils\Python25;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program
Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\Cle
arCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\Syst
em32\Citrix\IMA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\Citrix\IMA\Subsystems;C:\
WINDOWS\System32\Citrix\IMA;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\system32;C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\commonfiles\Citrix\System32\;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;c:\outils\cygw
in\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\commonfiles
\Citrix\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;lib\org.apache.an
t\bin
```

EDIT :
When I launch logoff with Ant, I got :

```
[exec] Disconnecting
[exec] "logoff.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"
```

Comment: why would a build log off?

Comment: Because, I'm running an Ant script periodically on a remote computer. I need to log off the remote session after build to avoid any conflict with the others.

Comment: Right... so what mechanism runs the ant build remotely?  How are you checking it's status? I'm pretty sure you're going to have a better time doing the log off there than in the ant script itself.

Comment: I'm calling mstsc command since Jenkins. In the rdp file in parameter, I launch a batch script which calls the build. But I want to run the build periodically during the night for instance. The problem is why ant cannot find the logoff command whereas everything is in the PATH variable

Comment: Is there a reason you don't run the jenkins slave service on the machine you're wanting to run the build on?   It would just work, you wouldn't have to mess with logging off.

Comment: I'm running jenkins slave agent on another computer exactly. I have some restrictions. But again, the problem is not here. When I launch a logoff from the console it's working and when I work with Ant it cannot be recognized, whereas simple "echo" works . Let's be clear I'm working in the remote session, no relation with Jenkins

Comment: wait... you have a jenkins master, a jenkins slave and then you're running the ant build on a third computer?  I truly believe your real solution will be to not do crazy stuff.

Comment: Everything works truly (except logoff)... I tried the ant logoff in another computer and same problem.

Comment: well the c:\windows\system32 is missing in PATH

Comment: I got the same error, then I removed JAVA_HOME and problem was solved...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot possibly imagine why anyone would ever do this in a build script.

Please don't do this.

But if you do, don't exec `cmd.exe` - call `logoff.exe` directly

```
<project name="logoff" default="logoff" basedir=".">
    <target name="logoff">
        <exec executable="logoff" />
    </target>
</project>
```

It's a very safe assumption that `logoff.exe` is on `%PATH%`, if for some reason it's not, set a property to get the absolute path to `logoff.exe`;

```
<project name="logoff" default="logoff" basedir=".">
    <property name="system32.dir" location="C:\Windows\System32" />        

    <target name="logoff">
        <exec executable="${system32.dir}\logoff" />
    </target>
</project>
```

I feel dirty for having typed this.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove that dir atribute.... This is working for me:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <project name="logoff" default="default" basedir=".">
        <target name="default">
        <exec executable="cmd">
            <arg value="/c"/>
            <arg value="logoff"/>
        </exec> 
    </target>
    </project>
```

**EDIT:**

```
@echo off
set ANT_HOME=W:\lib\org.apache.ant
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin 
set BUILD_PATH=W:\logoff.xml 
set ANT=call ant -buildfile %BUILD_PATH% 
%ANT% 
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now, I have "logoff is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" in an infinite loop

Comment: yes, maybe I have to set the PATH variable in the ANT target ?

Comment: are you running ant script from cmd? Yes, that can be a solution to your problem, because it looks like cmd cant find it, coz not looking in right dirs... try also shutdown /l instead logoff as mentioned down..

Comment: are you running it from cmd? Which directories do you have in PATH?

Comment: I'm running it from a bat which call the bat target (in build.xml) which call shutdown/logoff.

Comment: But shutdown and logoff work perfectly when I launch it from a simple batch script

Comment: It is strange. For me it is working... can you just upload somewhere exactly files which you are using and also echo of PATH?

Comment: please edit your question and type it into 2 different code block so it is easy to read... so we know what is in which file

Comment: can you post also that path variable?

Comment: You could try it with `<arg value="C:\windows\system32\logoff"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shutdown /l /f` instead, as suggested here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-force-logoff-from-command-line/8e7507e0-12c8-4ac7-8d5e-a1917e4af997

This might also help (description how to do it in java) as ant uses similar (to java) arguments:

[Shutdown Windows with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973643/shutdown-windows-with-java)