# Getting "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" when running WScript.Shell.Run() from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, wsh

**Background:**

I am trying to run C:\Windows\System32\Logoff.exe on a local machine from a ASP.NET web application to log off the local user from their terminal services session.

Here is what I have so far:

**C#**

```
protected void btnContinueClick(Object sender,
                       EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');\n");
        sb.Append(@"WshShell.Run('C:\\Windows\\System32\\Logoff.exe " + intSessionID + " /SERVER:" + strServer + "', 1, false);");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "RestartSession", sb.ToString(), true);
```

Running the above with IE's F12 menu open, shows the script gets added to my HTML successfully:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
WshShell.Run('C:\\Windows\\System32\\Logoff.exe', 1, false);//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
```

However when the Run(...) line executes I get the following error in IE:

```
Error: WshShell.Run()   Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Removing the ", 1, false" optional arguments = same error.
2. Moving the ' ' so the line reads (don't know which is correct): `sb.Append(@"WshShell.Run('C:\\Windows\\System32\\Logoff.exe " + intSessionID + " /SERVER:" + strServer + ", 1, false);'");` = same error.
3. Calling a .bat file with the logoff command inside. (The .bat does actually run, however I get a new error: `"logoff is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"`. Very similar to [Call logoff in Ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822540/call-logoff-in-ant-script).
4. Also changed escape characters around in as many possible combinations I can think of, so I don't think it is that.
5. Running the command directly from a CMD window does the intended job.

Please help!

Any suitable alternative methods of logging off a user's terminal services session from an internal Intranet web app would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Logoff` needs some parameters?

Comment: My plan was to replace the line with: `sb.Append(@"WshShell.Run('C:\\Windows\\System32\\Logoff.exe " + intSessionID + " /SERVER:" + strServer + ", 1, false');");` however this produces the same error. intSessionID and strServer are correct values for the Terminal Services session ID and server hostname.

Comment: Edited the question to show these parameters as I think they will be necessary when running from a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of variations, I have a working solution. Although the issue was most likely just with variable passing and escape characters (so quite trivial), I'm posting the answer anyway as it could point others towards a work-around when passing variables across multiple platforms.

**C#**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "Logoff", $"Logoff(\"{intSessionID}\", \"{strServer}\");", true);
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Logoff(intID, strSvr) {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Logoff.vbs" + " \"" + intID + "\" " + " \"" + strSvr + "\"", 1, false);
    }
</script>
```

The VB script then runs the original Logoff.exe command, along with a couple other audit logging lines.