# Java - shutdown computer after program run

Tags: java, logout, shutdown, system-shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutting down a computer using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer-using-java)

Hi,

I have a Java program that will run 20 times and take around 3 hours to do so. After this, I want my computer to shutdown, or for me to be logged off as a user. Can I do this directly from my program, i.e. directly after the for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
//APPLICATION CODE
}

//SHUTDOWN OR LOGGOF CODE
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an example you could run a system command like this:

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void shutDown() {
    try {
        Runtime
            .getRuntime()
            .exec(
                           "shutdown -s -t 120 -c \"Message telling shutdown has initiliazed. To stop the shutdown.\"");
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```