# System-independent machine shutdown in Java

Tags: java, platform-independent, system-shutdown, platform-independence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutting down a computer using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer-using-java)

I am making a personal program that will shut down my computer after a certain amount of time or at a certain time/date. However, I am running multiple operating systems and want to do this with one simple Java program. **Is there any way to send a system-independent machine shutdown request in Java without any using any external libraries?** I know you can use `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("shutdown /s"));` in Windows, but, again, I want system independence.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer-using-java

Comment: When taking that approach (which will be your only option), I suggest directly using `Runtime.exec()` instead of browsing some url on the desktop that looks like a command line.

Comment: The post that uses "operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name")", then "Runtime.exec()" based on the result, is absolutely his best bet.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` shuts down the Java Virtual Machine no matter what the underlying platform is.

Comment: I like the post http://stackoverflow.com/a/25650/348975 best.  Admittedly it is not very practical, but it would come the closest to system independence.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thank you! I was trying to think of the exact command, but couldn't find or remember it...

Comment: @emory That's not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@robjb gave me the best solution. Though it is a little too inflexible for my tastes, I will be suing it until I run into a problem.

```
  String shutdownCommand;
  StringPP operatingSystem = new StringPP(System.getProperty("os.name"));

  if (operatingSystem.containsIgnoreCase("linux") ||
      operatingSystem.containsIgnoreCase("mac") ||
      operatingSystem.containsIgnoreCase("unix"))
  {
    shutdownCommand = "sudo shutdown -h -t 30";
  }
  else if (operatingSystem.containsIgnoreCase("windows"))
  {
    shutdownCommand = "shutdown /s /d P:0:0 /t 30 /c \"Blue Husky Timer 2 is shutting down your system, as you requested. \n"
        + "You have 30 seconds to save and close programs\"";
  }
  else
  {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported operating system.");
  }

  try
  {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCommand);
  }
  catch (Throwable t)
  {
    Main.LOG.logThrowable(t);
  }
  System.exit(0);
```

In the above example, `StringPP` is a custom class that augments the capabilities of a `String` with methods such as the above used `#containsIgnoreCase`. `Main.LOG` is a logging utility that I made and use.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is not.

This is outside the scope of the JVM or standard Java class library.

Happy coding.

Comment: I would vote this up or accept this if it explained why. As it stands, it just **sounds** like a short-sighted opinion. Sorry...

Comment: @Supuhstar Honestly not sure what more there is to say :) The JDK is a general-purpose library. I do not know of *any* standard library for *any* language that has a system-shutdown command which is an operating-system feature. This includes C as many of the system-calls provided by the operating system (be it the Linux kernel or Windows and WinAPI) are *not* exposed in any way via stdlib. Only a subset of all operating system features are exposed as part of even POSIX API: I couldn't find on the "turn off a computer".

Comment: so... you're saying that "java.awt.Toolkit#shutdown()" is too system-specific? Why can't the individual JVMs handle the actual shutdown command, and the Java bytecode still be the same?

Comment: @Supuhstar Yes. I am saying precisely that. Please refer to above. You can *hide* system-specific behavior (as with the accepted answer), but it is *outside the scope of a standard library: and especially that of Java, as made clear the developers/designers who created it*.

Comment: how is shutting down the system outside the scope, but not taking control of the mouse and keyboard?

Comment: @Supuhstar "This is outside the scope of the JVM **or standard Java class library.**" That is, there is nothing intrinsically part of the JVM that allows it and there is nothing in the standard class library that allows it. AWT/Swing (or whatever UI is used in Android), considering for a moment those are "standard", *use native code* to allow keyboard/mouse access. This answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use schedulers?  All major operating systems supports such feature(cron, at etc).  There may be other factors like permission which comes to play in modern windows (windows 7 ), linux etc.

If you want to really use some system call,  Try  using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). That simplifies platform specific access a lot.

Comment: because there's more to this program than just scheduled shutdowns