# Shutdown Remote Computer in Java- Cannot initiate shutdown but no errors

Tags: java, shutdown

I am learning about the Runtime class in java, and am testing the use of command line instructions in it. I am trying to remotely shutdown a computer using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...); When I run this, there are no errors, but the specified machine does not shut down. I don't know why.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

class shutdownVirus {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -m \\\\T12-LEOPARDIJ -s -t 10");
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does the command work as expected when you run it directly from your command line (without Java in between)?

Comment: The `exec` method returns a `Process` object. Wait some time after calling it and check for the `exitValue` of the returned `Process` object and/or check if there is something written to standard or error out by reading from the streams returned by `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()`.

Comment: No, it says "T12-LEOPARDIJ- Access denied.(5)

Comment: how would you wait time after calling process object? and are you saying read from the streams from the process object?

Comment: May be you would like to try [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s");`

**Edited part:**

Use this.

`shutdown /s /m <Computer_Name>` **To shutdown a remote PC**

Comment: That works, but did YOU know that shutdown -s only shuts down the user, not a remote computer?

Comment: shutdown /s /m <COMPUTER NAME> – To shutdown a remote PC

Answer (score 2):

It probably does not work because the VM you are running the Java class with is started from a user that does not have shutdown rights. The process would inherit these access restrictions and therefore no be allowed to shut down.

Arguably thats a good thing..

Comment: By saying "arguably thats a good thing..." are you implying that I am attempting this for malicious means? Don't jump to conclusions...

Comment: I am not. Malicious or not the JVM should not be able to run anything outside the OS security constraints. I am not implying that you are doing something malicious. I am implying that you should get the right access rights to do what you want to do.