# Remote shutdown of client system using Java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

How do i remotely shutdown client/s system from server end ?
Also, how do i run any command on client/s command prompt ?
How do i send the line of codes to the client end from the server side ?
I've used ArrayList to send messages across the client earlier.

Answer (score -2):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

[Shutting down a computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Already been asked on here :)

For shutting down a computer remotely use:

```
shutdown /s /m <Computer_Name>
```

Link to that post aswell: [Shutdown Remote Computer in Java- Cannot initiate shutdown but no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183441/shutdown-remote-computer-in-java-cannot-initiate-shutdown-but-no-errors?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Sir , I know how to shutdown my own system using that.But I want to remotely shutdown a clients system . Also about my second question