# Processing - Shutdown a computer

Tags: java, processing, shutdown

I am working on a "Russian roulette" game in Processing, where one of the buttons shuts down the computer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use, in Linux:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -h now");
```

and in Windows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown.exe -s -t 0");
```

Finally put this sentence to terminate the process:

```
System.exit(0);
```

I expect it helps to you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, but the short answer is **yes**, this is possible.

However, it's also going to be OS specific: shutting down a Windows computer is different from shutting down a Mac computer, etc.

You can start by googling "java shutdown computer" for a ton of results, but a very basic attempt (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer) SO question) is something like this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
```