# How to lock, shutdown, restart and suspend the pc with runtime.exec in java?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

How to lock, shutdown, restart and suspend the pc with runtime.exec in java?

I want to make a jar for windows and linux os.

I want to lock, shutdown, restart and suspend the pc programmatically.

I tried this code.

```
package poweroff;

import mousekeyboardcontrol.MouseKeyboardControl;


public class PowerOff {
String os;
Runtime runtime;
public PowerOff() {
    os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
}

public void shutdown() {     
    try {
        if ("Windows 8.1".equals(os) || "Windows 8.0".equals(os) || "Windows 10".equals(os)) {
            runtime.exec("shutdown -s");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unsupported operating system");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("shutdown error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public void restart() {     
    try {
        if ("Windows 8.1".equals(os) || "Windows 8.0".equals(os) || "Windows 10".equals(os)) {
            runtime.exec("shutdown -r");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unsupported operating system");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("restart error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public void suspend() {     
    try {
        if ("Windows 8.1".equals(os) || "Windows 8.0".equals(os) || "Windows 10".equals(os)) {
            runtime.exec("Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unsupported operating system");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("suspend error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public void lock() {     
    try {
        if ("Linux".equals(os) || "Mac OS X".equals(os)) {
            new MouseKeyboardControl().ctrlAltL();
        } else if ("Windows 8.1".equals(os) || "Windows 8.0".equals(os) || "Windows 10".equals(os)) {
            runtime.exec("Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unsupported operating system");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("pc lock error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    PowerOff powerOff = new PowerOff();
    powerOff.lock();
}
}
```

But, it not worked.

I want to lock, shutdown, restart and suspend with programmatically in java for windows 7, 8, 10 and all linux os.

How can I solve this?

Comment: "But, it not worked.": What happened?

Comment: shutdown might require elevated privileges (UAC)

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use the command line tools of each OS with appropriate flags. See here for instance for [linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shut-down#578155).
See also this answer on another example [Shutting down a computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637/shutting-down-a-computer)

For Windows shutdown try: `"shutdown -s -t 0"`
For Windows Restart try: `"shutdown -r -t 0"`
For Windows Hibernate try: `"shutdown -h -t 0"`

For Linux shutdown try: `"shutdown now"`
For Linux restart try: `"reboot now"`

Tip: If you can introduce dependencies, using [SystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html) from Apache Commons could help check the OS version correctly in an easy to read/maintain manner.